# UIComponent button is not printing like it looks on screen

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I have an area on a screen I would like to print and when I create a print job the buttons on the screen lose their background / look. I haven't tested this with other components but I'm guessing I'll run into this more. The text looks fine but not the image. How do I get it to keep it's look?

**In application:**

[image]

**After print in Mac Preview program:**

[image]

BTW I know there are things like AlievePDF but I don't want to use that. I want to know what is going on here and how to fix it without it.

Comment: When you add the page to the PrintJob, are you specifying options with printAsBitmap=true?  I ran into similar issues, and I can't remember which way caused the printout to be wonky, but this looks familiar...

Comment: I was trying to avoid printing in bitmap format but I'll give it a try.

Comment: If I use printAsBitmap it prints it correctly so that's good but then everything is rasterized which for those who don't know means that as you scale up the images are pixelated. If you use vector graphics the objects that are vector retain their sharpness when you scale up.